# How to write lines in a txt file, with data from a csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

How can I tell Python to open a CSV file, and merge all columns per line, into new lines in a new TXT file?

To explain:

I'm trying to download a bunch of member profiles from a website, for a research project. To do this, I want to write a list of all the URLs in a TXT file.

The URLs are akin to this: website.com-name-country-title-id.html

I have written a script that takes all these bits of information for each member and saves them in columns (name/country/title/id), in a CSV file, like this:

```
mark    japan    rookie    married
john    sweden   expert    single
suzy    germany    rookie    married
etc...
```

Now I want to open this CSV and write a TXT file with lines like these:

```
www.website.com/mark-japan-rookie-married.html
www.website.com/john-sweden-expert-single.html
www.website.com/suzy-germany-rookie-married.html
etc...
```

Here's the code I have so far. As you can probably tell I barely know what I'm doing so help will be greatly appreciated!!!

```
import csv
x = "http://website.com/"
y = ".html"

csvFile=csv.DictReader(open("NameCountryTitleId.csv")) #This file is stored on my computer
file = open("urls.txt", "wb")

for row in csvFile:
    strArgument=str(row['name'])+"-"+str(row['country'])+"-"+str(row['title'])+"-"+str(row['id'])
    try:
        file.write(x + strArgument + y)
    except:
        print(strArgument)

file.close()
```

I don't get any error messages after running this, but the TXT file is completely empty.

Comment: There is nothing in your code to suggest your file fails to write. Perhaps it is being written in a different location from what you expected?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it was being written to a different location. But your way of doing it is better, so thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a `DictReader`, use a regular reader to make it easier to join the row:

```
import csv

url_format = "http://website.com/{}.html"
csv_file = 'NameCountryTitleId.csv'
urls_file = 'urls.txt'

with open(csv_file, 'rb') as infh, open(urls_file, 'w') as outfh:
    reader = csv.reader(infh)
    for row in reader:
        url = url_format.format('-'.join(row))
        outfh.write(url + '\n')
```

The `with` statement ensures the files are closed properly again when the code completes.

Further changes I made:

- In Python 2, open a CSV files in binary mode, the `csv` module handles line endings itself, because correctly quoted column data can have embedded newlines in them.
- Regular text files should be opened in text mode still though.
- When writing lines to a file, do remember to add a newline character to delineate lines.
- Using a string format (`str.format()`) is far more flexible than using string concatenations.
- `str.join()` lets you join a sequence of strings together with a separator.

Answer (score -1):

its actually quite simple, you are working with strings yet the file you are opening to write to is being opened in bytes mode, so every single time the write fails and it prints to the screen instead. try changing this line:

```
file = open("urls.txt", "wb")
```

to this:

```
file = open("urls.txt", "w")
```

EDIT:
i stand corrected, however i would like to point out that with an absence of newlines or some other form of separator, how do you intend to use the URLs later on? if you put newlines between each URL they would be easy to recover

Comment: In Python 2, the only difference this makes is translation of newlines to the platform-native line separator. The OP is not even writing newlines, and it certainly won't raise an exception.